# How to display an error message in django formset with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, formset

I'm trying to submit a django formset using ajax,  but the problem is that I can't iterate the error fields and it give me each error to its form and field!

```
class Vistor(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=14)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['full_name','dob','city'],name='full_information')
        ]
```

And also I've used ModelForm

```
class VistorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=City.objects.all())    

    class Meta:
        model = Vistor
        fields = [
          'full_name','dob','city'
        ]
VistorFormSet = modelformset_factory(Vistor,form=VistorForm,extra=1,can_delete=True)
```

`non_fields_error` defined as `__all__` in ajax call error messages

```
@login_required
def add_vistor(request):
    formset = VistorFormSet(queryset=Vistor.objects.none())
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        formset = VistorFormSet(request.POST)            
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                if form.cleaned_data !={}:
                obj.admin = request.user
                obj.save()
        
            formset = VistorFormSet(queryset=City.objects.none())
            return JsonResponse({'success':'success'})
        else:
            return 
    JsonResponse({'success':False,'error_msg':formset.errors,'error_code':'invalid'})

return render(request,'vistors/add_vistor.html',{'formset':formset})
```

my html + js

```js
//for adding new form
$('#addButton').click(function() {
    var form_dex1 = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('#form').append($('#formset').html().replace(/__prefix__/g,form_dex1));
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_dex1) + 1);
    });
  
 //ajax submit form
     const form = document.getElementById('post-form')
    form.addEventListener("submit",submitHandler);

    function submitHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url 'vistors:add_vistor' %}',
            data : $('#post-form').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: successFunction,
        });
    }
    function successFunction(data) {
        console.log(data.success=='success')
        if (data.success=='success') {
            alertify.success("added")  

            form.reset();              

        }
        else if(data.error_code=='invalid'){
          console.log(data.error_msg.length)
            for(var i=0; i < data.error_msg.length;i++){
              console.log(data.error_msg)
                if(key == 'full_name'){
                    document.getElementById('full_name_error').removeAttribute('hidden')
                    document.getElementById('full_name_error').innerHTML = data.error_msg[key][0]

                }
                if(key == 'dob'){
                    document.getElementById('dob_error').removeAttribute('hidden')
                    document.getElementById('dob_error').innerHTML = data.error_msg[key][0]

                }
                if(key == 'city'){
                    document.getElementById('city_error').removeAttribute('hidden')
                    document.getElementById('city_error').innerHTML = data.error_msg[key][0]

                }
 
                if(key == '__all__'){
                    document.getElementById('full_name_error').removeAttribute('hidden')
                    document.getElementById('full_name_error').innerHTML = data.error_msg[key][0]

                }                                
            }
        }
  }
```

```html
    <div class="z-30 w-full p-2 mt-3 bg-white bg-opacity-75 shadow-lg  md:mt-0 md:top-32 rounded-xl md:absolute md:right-0" >             
        <button id="addButton" class="px-4 py-1 pb-2 text-white focus:outline-none header rounded-xl">
            add new form
            <i class="bi bi-plus"></i>
        </button>
          
        <form id="post-form" method="POST" class="mt-2 ">{% csrf_token %}
            
            {% for form in formset.forms %}
            {{ form.id }}
            
            <div id="form" class="grid md:grid-cols-3 gap-16 md:gap-x-3 md:gap-y-8">
                {{formset.management_form}}
                <!-- first form -->
                <div class="relative p-2 bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-25 border border-gray-900 rounded-xl pb-14">
                

                <div class="relative groupinput bglightpurple rounded-xl">
                    <label class="absolute mt-1 mr-2 text-xs text-white top-1">full name</label>
                    {{form.full_name | add_class:'w-full pt-6 pb-1 pr-2 text-white bg-transparent focus:outline-none'}}
                    <p class="w-full pb-2 pr-2 text-white rounded-xl" id="full_name_error" hidden>error</p>


                </div>
                
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-1">
                    <div class="relative mt-2 groupinput bglightpurple rounded-xl">
                        <label class="absolute mt-1 mr-2 text-xs text-white top-1">dob</label>

                        {{form.dob | add_class:'w-full pt-6 pb-1 pr-2 text-white bg-transparent focus:outline-none'}}
                            <p class="w-full pb-2 pr-2 text-white rounded-xl" id="dob_error" hidden>error</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-wrap justfiy-between md:gap-1">
                    <div class="w-9/12 relative mt-2 groupinput bglightpurple rounded-xl">

                            <label class="absolute mt-1 mr-2 text-xs text-white top-1">city </label>
                            {{form.city | add_class:'w-full pt-6 pb-1 pr-2 text-white bg-transparent focus:outline-none'}}
                            <p class="w-9/12 pb-2 pr-2 text-white rounded-xl" id="city_error" hidden>error</p>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      <div id="formset" class="grid md:grid-cols-3 gap-16 md:gap-x-3 md:gap-y-8" style="display: none;">
                <!-- formset -->
                <div class="relative p-2 bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-25 border border-gray-900 rounded-xl pb-14">
                

                <div class="relative groupinput bglightpurple rounded-xl">
                    <label class="absolute mt-1 mr-2 text-xs text-white top-1">full name</label>
                    {{formset.empty_form.full_name | add_class:'w-full pt-6 pb-1 pr-2 text-white bg-transparent focus:outline-none'}}
                    <p class="w-full pb-2 pr-2 text-white rounded-xl" id="full_name_set_error" hidden>error</p>
                

                </div>
                
                <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-1">
                    <div class="relative mt-2 groupinput bglightpurple rounded-xl">
                            <label class="absolute mt-1 mr-2 text-xs text-white top-1">dob</label>
                            {{formset.empty_form.dob | add_class:'w-full pt-6 pb-1 pr-2 text-white bg-transparent focus:outline-none'}}
                            <p class="w-full pb-2 pr-2 text-white rounded-xl" id="dob_set_error" hidden>error</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="relative mt-2 groupinput bglightpurple rounded-xl">
                            <label class="absolute mt-1 mr-2 text-xs text-white top-1">city </label>
                            {{formset.empty_form.city | add_class:'w-full pt-6 pb-1 pr-2 text-white bg-transparent focus:outline-none'}}
                            <p class="w-full pb-2 pr-2 text-white rounded-xl" id="city_set_error" hidden>error</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="px-6 py-1 mt-6 text-white rounded-lg header ">save</button>

       </form>

    </div>
```

But I can't do that , and errors returns in an array dictionary , for example : for the constraint fields (unique fields together) it returns this in the console !

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @SteveSmith unfortunately not yet